# parallelize Java program

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, acceleration

How do I parallelize the program on Java so that the execution time of a parallel version was (much) less than execution time of program without threads?
I tried e.g. the `ExecutorService` (["Parallel.For" for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010185/parallel-for-for-java)) but it works about 3 times longer

Is the problem that I use threads in Java improperly or it is unreal to get acceleration in 2 times with 2 cores (is this possible with 4 cores?)?

P.S. I need to parallelize `while` loop

Comment: It's impossible to answer without seeing your code - the problem could be due to numerous reasons...

Answer (score 0):

Multithreading programming is useful in the following situations:

- Multi core systems needed when intensive in memory operations (not needed if there are long I/O operations like the following)
- Database operations (perform queries)
- Network operations (like sending file or call a web service)
- File operations (read write a file)

If you are not in one of the previous situations adding multithreading results in a slower application due to the overhead of switching between processes.

Comment: This is misleading at best: using multithreading on file operations is most likely going to be slower. And using multithreading on computationally intensive tasks should be in your list.

Comment: Using multithread in file operations like read write file is not slower. Generally multithreading is useful always when the cpu is not used at 100%. This happens often for any non in memory operation. Using multithreading for Intensive tasks in a mono core system (one cpu) is not useful. I edit my post to be more clear.

Comment: Re. file read write, assuming we are talking about a local hard drive, the bottleneck is the hard drive - throwing more threads at it will only slow it down.... See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584797/multithreaded-file-copy-is-far-slower-than-a-single-thread-on-a-multicore-cpu

Comment: It depends on many factors. You can have a file read and a subsequent operation in memory and save the results to a remote db. You can do that efficiently with multithreading. Reading from a file is a slow operation so if you have a long operation to do in memory you can use the time needed to read the data from the file to elaborate the data already read before.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend this thread to you, since it goes into pretty good detail on the subject: [[Java 8's streams: why parallel stream is slower?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23170832/java-8s-streams-why-parallel-stream-is-slower][1])

The long and short of it, parallelism introduces overhead and complexity to any process, and while there are certainly gains to be had by parallelization, it won't work out to 2 threads on 2 cores = 2x faster.