# In a well-running multithreaded app, a defined callback will not be called. Why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qthread, qcoreapplication

I have a program that starts five threads. Every single thread says 'Hello World!' to the console. At the end of a thread a callback function should be called. This outputs 'Goodby folks' to the console.

To show that threading works, the runtimes of each individual thread are measured and reported. For comparison, the total running time is measured and reported as well.

The total runtime corresponds to the runtime of the longest-running thread. But the output 'Goodby folks' is missing all five times.

Output looks like:

```
saying Hello World! took 0.126 s
saying Hello World! took 0.439 s
saying Hello World! took 0.645 s
saying Hello World! took 0.994 s
saying Hello World! took 1.469 s

total runtime is 1.479 s
```

Please, who can tell me, what's wrong here?

```
import random
import sys
import time
from typing import Callable

from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QThread, QObject, pyqtSignal


class MeasureRuntime:
    def __enter__(self):
        self.__start = time.perf_counter()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.__stop = time.perf_counter()
        self.elapsed = self.__stop - self.__start
        return True


class MyQtThreads(QObject):

    def __enter__(self):
        self.__running_threads: list = []
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.__waitForThreadsListEmpty()
        return True

    def __waitForThreadsListEmpty(self):
        while self.__running_threads:
            for thread in self.__running_threads:
                if thread.isFinished():
                    self.__running_threads.pop(self.__running_threads.index(thread))

    def doInThread(self, fn, *args, callback: Callable = None, **kwargs) -> int:
        thread = MyQtThread(fn, *args, **kwargs)
        if callback:
            thread.SIG_FINISHED.connect(callback)
        self.__running_threads.append(thread)
        thread.start()
        return id(thread)


class MyQtThread(QThread):
    SIG_FINISHED = pyqtSignal(object)

    def __init__(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()

        self.fn = fn
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def run(self):
        ret = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        result_info = {"thread_id": id(self), "args": ret}
        self.SIG_FINISHED.emit(result_info)


def say_hello():
    with MeasureRuntime() as rt:
        random.seed()
        time.sleep(random.random()*3)
        print(f'saying Hello World! took ', end='')
    print(f'{rt.elapsed:.3f} s')


def say_adieu(args):
    print('Goodby folks')


class Main(QThread):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):

        print()
        with MeasureRuntime() as rt:

            with MyQtThreads() as threads:
                for _ in range(5):
                    threads.doInThread(say_hello, callback=say_adieu)

        print(f'\ntotal runtime is {rt.elapsed:.3f} s')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    qcoreapp = QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
    thread = Main()
    thread.finished.connect(qcoreapp.exit)
    thread.start()
    qcoreapp.exec()
```

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: first I would check if it execute code inside `if callback:` and line `self.SIG_FINISHED.emit(result_info)`

Comment: @furas I did this. Yes, the if clause is reached. A print before emit and after emit will performed. So the callback function should be registered. Same with emit.

Comment: I can't confirm this but I think code finish so fast and it has no time to receive emited signals. If I add `QtCore.QCoreApplication.processEvents()` after `print(f'\ntotal runtime ...")` then I get messages `'Goodby folks'` on screen. I found this function in (downvoted) answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45558060/1832058

Comment: Yes indeed!! Thank you very much for your effort and this advice!!!!

Comment: or maybe problem is that you don't have any GUI and maybe it doesn't run any `processEvents` so it can't receive any events.

Comment: Interesting thought. But as far as I know, the last line starts an event loop. For non-GUI based applications, there's QCoreApplication for that purpose, isn't there? Or am I misinformed?

Comment: I never created non-GUI in PyQt. It would need to read documentation, or check source code (to see how works `QCoreApplication`), or you would have to ask authors of [Qt forum](https://forum.qt.io/) :)